# how to get value from <h:selectOneMenu>?

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

i want to get the value from . i tryed this code but it doesn't work :

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="départements : "/>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{departementController.selected.id}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
            <f:valueChangeListener type="Controller.Listener.DepartementValueListener"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{departementController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputLabel value="nouvelle valeur : "/>

        <h:inputText value="#{departementController.comboBox}" id="dep"/>
    </h:form>
```

the controller :

```
 //departement change listener
private String comboBox;

public String getComboBox() {
    return comboBox;
}

public void setComboBox(String comboBox) {
    this.comboBox = comboBox;
}

public void departementChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    // Skip validation of non-immediate components and invocation of the submit() method.
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    this.comboBox = e.getNewValue().toString();}
```

sourceId=j_idt7:j_idt9[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt7:j_idt9 : erreur de validation. La valeur est incorrecte.), detail=(j_idt7:j_idt9 : erreur de validation. La valeur est incorrecte.)]

Comment: Which JSF version are you using?

Comment: am using jpa2.0 + jsf2.0 + ejb3.0+primefaces3.2

Comment: the code source of the page : nouvelle valeur : </label><input id="j_idt7:dep" type="text" name="j_idt7:dep" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-7060370113585400772:-6095599445324372450" autocomplete="off" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've after all 2 problems.

First, the error *"erreur de validation. La valeur est incorrecte"* which is the French translation of *"Validation Error: Value is not valid"* means that the submitted value doesn't `equals()` any one of the available items in `<f:selectItems>`. Your code is not complete enough to point out the root cause, but I *guess* that you've a `List<Department>` there in `<f:selectItems value>` and thus every item is `Department`, but you're trying to set it as a `String` value of `id` instead of as `Department`. This is not right. You need to supply a converter between `Department` and `String` and use `#{departementController.selected}` instead.

Something like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedDepartment}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableDepartments}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
private Department selectedDepartment;
private List<Department> availableDepartments;
```

And a `@FacesConverter` which converts between `Department` and its unique `String` representation.

Your second problem is that you seem to be focusing too much on JSF 1.x targeted examples as to populating another field on change of the dropdown. You're using a rather clumsy/hacky JSF 1.x workaround for that. In JSF 2.x you can just use `<f:ajax>` for this.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedDepartment}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableDepartments}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeDepartment}" render="inputId" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText id="inputId" value="#{bean.input}" />
```

with

```
public void changeDepartment() {
    input = selectedDepartment.getId();
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our selectonemenu wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Moving the listener inside the backing bean substantially simplifies the problem by making the selected item directly available in it's `Department` form. But what if you want a `generic` listener that could do the job for you on any selectOneMenu (independent of specific backing beans)?